# Google.maps panTo

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to center my map on the center of a custom infoBox. Instead, I am panning to a completely different place, far from my map markers. Here is my code:

```
var projection = this.getProjection(),
    centerX = point.x - (125)/2, 
    centerY = point.y - (120)/2, 
    centerPoint = new google.maps.Point(centerX, centerY);
var latLngOfBoxTop = projection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(centerPoint);
this.map.panTo(latLngOfBoxTop);
```

What is a better way to pan to a point on the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out and never updated my own question. It was easy: I simply set the center of the map to the marker's location (a latitude and longitude that I already have), and then I used "panBy", which takes pixels as its parameters, not latitude and longitude:

```
    var latlng = this.latlng_,
        div_height = $('#infobox-wrap-' + markerID).css('height').replace(/px/, ''),
        infoBoxHalfHeight = 0, 
        halfDivHeight = Math.round(div_height/2);

    infoBoxHalfHeight = halfDivHeight + 16; //accounts for the infoBox's "pointer" graphic

    this.map.setCenter(latlng);
    this.map.panBy(0, infoBoxHalfHeight);
```